# AngularJs Empty data with $scope controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've ben struggling with this for days, I can't see where is wrong. Thing is I've set up a angularjs web with routing and controllers but the controllers are showing the data empty in the views, but in the console I can see the $scope output with the corect data throught a console.log($scope). Here is the code

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
/script><sctipt src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
/sctipt><script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="wrap">
            <p class="form-title">
                {{signin}}</p>
            <form class="login">
            <input type="text" ng-placeholder="{{user}}" required/>
            <input type="password" ng-placeholder="{{password}}" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="{{signin}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
            <div class="remember-forgot">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                {{rememberme}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 forgot-pass-content">
                        <a href="javascription:void(0)" class="forgot-pass">{{forgotpassword}}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider',function ($locationProvider,$routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/login',{
        templateUrl:'html/login.html',
        controller:'loginController'
    }).
    when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'html/home.html',
        controller:'homeController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/login'
    });
}]);

app.run(function($rootScope){
$rootScope.urlapi='http://freecalendar.desirnet.com/api/api.php';
});

app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$rootScope,$location){
$scope={
    'singin':'Iniciar sesión',
    'user':'Usuario',
    'password':'Contraseña',
    'rememberme':'Recuérdame',
    'forgotpassword':'Recordar contraseña'
};
console.log($scope);

$scope.login=function(){
    var data=$.param({
        'user':$scope.txtuser,
        'password':$scope.txtpassword
    });

    $http.post($rootScope.urlapi,data)
    .then(function(response){
        response=response.data;
        console.log(response);
        if(response.error!=undefined){
            $scope.errorlogin="El usuario y/o contraseña no son correctos";
        } else {
            $location.path('/home')
        }
    });
}
});

app.controller('homeController',function($scope,$rootScope,$location){
});
```

I really don't know what I'nm doing wrong, I follow many routing tutorials, but nothing.

In the console there are no errors only the $scope output.

Comment: One issue is typo in '`singin'` in your $scope declaration.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

typographical error in these line of code:

/sctipt>

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to the $scope parameter in your loginController function

```
$scope={
    'singin':'Iniciar sesión',
    'user':'Usuario',
    'password':'Contraseña',
    'rememberme':'Recuérdame',
    'forgotpassword':'Recordar contraseña'
};
```

You need to understand that after that you loose the link to the actual scope Angular is using. Angular simply has no way of knowing what are you intentions in your controller.

Here is the piece of code that will do the trick:

```
Object.assign($scope, {
    'singin':'Iniciar sesión',
    'user':'Usuario',
    'password':'Contraseña',
    'rememberme':'Recuérdame',
    'forgotpassword':'Recordar contraseña'
});
```

Notice that it simply adds a few properties to the $scope object therefore Angular can perfectly reflect changes from your controller in your view.